# need to detect i2c value in uboot as a script

Tags: i2c, u-boot

I wish to read a value from i2c in uboot,
and based on the value, do a command. I need it to be in a script

The command itself does not matter, however, its activation must be based on the value from the i2c chip.

So far I can only print values from i2c, but I cannot use them.

```
=> i2c md 20.1 0 8
0000: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ........
```

I can also have conditions:

```
=> setenv myvalue 0
=> if test $myvalue -eq 1; then echo 'hello'; fi
=> setenv myvalue 1
=> if test $myvalue -eq 1; then echo 'hello'; fi
hello
=>
```

I can do some of them specific to i2c:

```
=> if i2c probe; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
Valid chip addresses: 20 21 22 23
true
```

But I cannot use the values from the i2c to a condition. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any straightforward way to do this, but the following should work:

1. Read your I2C data into memory somewhere using `i2c read`.
2. Write the comparison value elsewhere into memory using `mw`.
3. Compare the two memory areas using `cmp` - this should work in the form `if cmp` to conditionally do something based on the result.

You would somehow have to know the addresses of a block of RAM on your particular system that could be safely written to at this stage of the boot process.

Answer (score 0):

There is no provided solution within u-boot to achieve what you are after (easily).  I have written a u-boot command which allows you to read from RAM and store the value into an environment variable which allows you to do a comparison.

```
#include <common.h>
#include <config.h>
#include <command.h>

int do_setenvram(
    cmd_tbl_t *cmdtp,
    int flag,
    int argc,
    char *argv[]
) {

    unsigned int *addr;
    unsigned long len;
    uint32_t val;
    char buffer[200];
    char type;
    char returntype;

    if ( argc < 3 || argc > 4 )  {
        printf ("Usage:\n%s\n", cmdtp->usage);
        return 1;
    }

    addr = (char *)simple_strtol(argv[2], NULL, 16);

    if ( !addr ) {
        printf ("Usage:\n%s\n", cmdtp->usage);
        return 1;
    }

    if ( argc == 4 ) {
        len = simple_strtol(argv[3], NULL, 16);
        if ( !len || len >= buffer ) {
            printf ("Usage:\n%s\n", cmdtp->usage);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int option = strlen(argv[0]);

    if ( option > 2 && argv[0][option-3] == '.' ) {
        type = argv[0][option-2];
        returntype = argv[0][option-1];
    } else if ( option > 2 && argv[0][option-2] == '.' ) {
        type = argv[0][option-1];
    } else {
        printf ("Usage:\n%s\n", cmdtp->usage);
        return 1;
    }

    switch ( type ) {
        case 'b':
            val = *((unsigned char *)(addr));
            break;
        case 'w':
            addr = (unsigned short *)simple_strtol(argv[2], NULL, 16);
            val = ntohs(*addr);
            break;
        case 'l':
            addr = (unsigned int *)simple_strtol(argv[2], NULL, 16);
            val = htonl(*addr);
            break;
        case 'k':
            addr = (unsigned int *)simple_strtol(argv[2], NULL, 16);
            val = (*addr);
            break;
        case 's':
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
            memcpy(buffer, addr, len);
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }

    if ( returntype == 'd' ) {
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", val);
    } else if ( type != 's' ) {
        sprintf(buffer, "0x%x", val);
    }

    setenv(argv[1], buffer);
    return 0;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

U_BOOT_CMD(
    setenvram, 4, 0, do_setenvram,
    "set environment variable from ram",
    "name addr {len}\n"
    "[.b, .w, .l, .s, .k] name address {max_length}\n"
    "    - set environment variable 'name' from addr 'addr'\n"
);
```

So in your case:

1. Read from i2c into a location in memory (which is free or able to be written over): `i2c read <chip> <memory-location>`
2. Confirm that it is written in the memory location provided: `md <memory-location>`
3. You need to know the expected data that you will be reading from memory, in the sense of the length and whether it is big endian or little endian.
4. You will be able to use the u-boot command that I have supplied above by doing `setenvram.x <variable-name> <memory-location> <length>` where argument `.x` is one of the following:

> Argument[1] options:
>
> .b - bit (1 byte).
>
> .w - word (2 bytes). Host-Network byte converted.
>
> .l - long (4 bytes). Host-Network byte converted.
>
> .k - long (4 bytes).
>
> .s - string (num of bytes specified by user). // Note: {length} is required.

5. From here on the values stored in memory will now be in a u-boot environment variable which can be used for comparison.

Further examples and usage can be seen in the commit here: https://github.com/bwenstar/uboot-imx/commit/5996e854f82ecb9005d2b9546a71fca458784204